# How to "archive" a project including all dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm working on a complex microservices project spread out over multiple repositories. As this project is coming to an end, I would like to save a local copy. Just zipping the project onto an external drive is not enough, as the IDE would not find any reference to the external libraries.

What I would like to achieve: package this entire project with all of it's dependencies into 1 folder/directory, so that it isn't dependent on `~/.m2/repository/...`.
Probably packaging the entire project into a `.jar` would be the best pick, right?
But can this be opened and recognized as a project by let's say IntelliJ IDEA?

As a side question: I'm pretty sure I'm not the only developer who likes to save his work for future reference, in case I come up with an issue down the road and thinking *"Darn it, how did I solve this again?"*. But what are the best practices to archiving this in general? Just zipping the entire thing onto a thumbdrive? Curious to hear about your methods!

Comment: Isn't your code in git?

Comment: I don't know of any defined best practices, but I'd try to  1. create a new directory for all the stuff below, 1. clone all git repositories into it, 2. set up a `settings.xml` with a local repository path *inside* that new directory 3. run `mvn dependency:go-offline` in each maven project (using the `--settings` switch to point to the file created in #2) 4. zip/tar.gz up the whole thing. An optional 3a. would be to tweak the `settings.xml` to ensure no more updates are ever checked for and/or remove all remote repositories and/or enable offline mode by default, however that works.

Comment: @JoachimSauer This sounds like a relatively future proof way. Maybe also put copy of Maven and Java beside it, in the correct versions.

Comment: Yes, good point. *In addition* to that archive, you could also try to provide a docker image that's all set up for building. That would simplify getting started (as long as docker is a thing, which is why I'd only ever do it in addition to the archive).

Comment: @JFabianMeier yes, but this is an enterprise repository, project finished = access revoked. So I'm guessing you're leaning towards creating my own private git repository and cloning all of the repos into my own one?

Comment: Kind of strange enterprise repository ... then I would clone all the git repositories, if allowed.

Comment: Are you sure you are allowed to keep a copy of the source code once the project is finished?